# Installing Apache Wave on Debian Jessie

Tags: java, debian, google-wave

I want to install Apache/Google Wave on Debian Jessie. I checked out the SVN repository, but building with ant fails since Java 6 is required. Debian Jessie only offers Java 7 Openjdk via apt-get. I tried to download the Java 6 bin file from Oracle Website, but ant is not included in that bin file. As a note: Later I want to install BaseX on the same server which requires Java 7. Alternative: Is there an open Wave host?

Answer (score 2):

Apache Wave uses java 7. SVN? I think you are using and old SVN repository. Apache Wave now uses a [git repository](https://incubator.apache.org/wave/source-code.html).

Open Wave host? There are some [demo servers](https://incubator.apache.org/wave/demo-servers.html). Our software [Kune](http://kune.ourproject.org/) is based in Apache Wave and has it's own debian package. Kune is focused in groups collaboration and free/libre/open culture. Also you can try our [kune.cc](http://kune.cc) production service.